# Merging Many PDFs into One PDF

Tags: python, pdf

I am trying to merge 4 PDF documents into 1 PDF document but I am getting a type error which states that I Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly. How can I fix this issue and will the code that I have attempted below merge all my PDFs into One?

```
# Script to generate a PDF report containing all PDFs
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger
import os

path = 'H:\College Fourth Year\Development Project\Final Year Project 2018\Forensic Reports'

pdf_files = ['Call Log Data Report.pdf','Canonical Address Data Report.pdf', 'Sim Card Data Report.pdf', 'SMS Data Report.pdf']

merger = PdfFileMerger()

for files in pdf_files:
    merger.append(path + pdf_files)
if not os.path.exists(path + 'Full Report.pdf'):
    merger.write(path + 'Full Report.pdf')
merger.close()

# Stack Trace Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:/College Fourth Year/Development Project/Final Year Project 2018/All_Data_Report.py", line 17, in <module>
    merger.append(path + files)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\merger.py", line 203, in append
    self.merge(len(self.pages), fileobj, bookmark, pages, import_bookmarks)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\merger.py", line 114, in merge
    fileobj = file(fileobj, 'rb')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'H:\\College Fourth Year\\Development Project\\Final Year Project 2018\\Forensic ReportsCall Log Data Report.pdf'



# Updated Code
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger
import os

path = r'H:\College Fourth Year\Development Project\Final Year Project 2018\Forensic Reports'

pdf_files = ['Call Log Data Report.pdf','Canonical Address Data Report.pdf', 'Sim Card Data Report.pdf', 'SMS Data Report.pdf']

merger = PdfFileMerger()

for files in pdf_files:
    PdfFileMerger.append(path + files)
if not os.path.exists(path + 'Full Report.pdf'):
    merger.write(path + 'Full Report.pdf')
merger.close()
```

Comment: Look carefully at this line of your stack trace: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'H:\\College Fourth Year\\Development Project\\Final Year Project 2018\\Forensic ReportsCall Log Data Report.pdf'`. Is the file you are after named `Forensic ReportsCall Log Data Report.pdf`, or `Foresic Reports\Call Log Data Report.pdf`? It looks to me like you are missing a `\ `.

Comment: I was missing a '\'. Its working now. I generated a merged PDF report with the each tables data separated into a page of its own. It is exactly what I required. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On this line

```
 merger.append(path + pdf_files)
```

You wanted

```
 merger.append(path + files)
```

Comment: Apologies. I have just seen "merger.append(path + pdf_files)" in the error. so this line must be changed as advised.

Comment: I have changed merger.append(path _ pdf_files) to merger.append(path + files) but I am still getting an issue. The full stack trace is posted above.

Comment: I am now getting the error that says "File "H:/College Fourth Year/Development Project/Final Year Project 2018/All_Data_Report.py", line 17, in <module>
    PdfFileMerger.append(path + files)
TypeError: append() missing 1 required positional argument: 'fileobj'"